# Sharepoint 2013 Foundation move content server to server

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I have two servers on my farm, same domain, same subnet.  The databases are hosted on a separate SQL Server (call it server 3 for ease).  I need to move everything from server one (original Sharepoint install) to server two (new install).  I added server 2 to the farm, joined to the databases on server 3 and started it up.  It works but I cannot access the content on the new server, if I try, I just get the navigation bar at the top of the screen but no content (libraries etc). I obviously missed something, how do I move the content over given that the databases are on a separate server.  All the articles I can find talk about moving the databases, but I don't need to as they are not on the server to be decommissioned.

Further info:

Server 1 - Windows 2012 - Sharepoint Foundation 2013 - Up to date

Server 2 - Windows 2016 - Sharepoint Foundation 2013 - Up to date

Server 3 - Windows 2012 - SQL Server 2012 Standard

Comment: It sounds like your problem may be related to phrasing. You're not trying to move content, you're trying to add another web front end server to your existing SharePoint farm. Have you already seen [this documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc261752.aspx)?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, turns out the content was there, it just hadn't refreshed. Hitting F5 in the browser caused it to load the whole page rather than just the top bar. Your explanation did help though, I didn't realise that I was just putting a new WFE on and I didn't need to move any data.